# Google+ vs Google+ Local

Tags: seo, google, google-plus

My client has both a Google+ and a Google+ Local account.

Although I can find no definitive answer, it seems that each serve a different purpose and it is not the case as I first thought that they should only use a single Google+ account.

This means I need to link both accounts to their website. The process for linking a Google+ account to a website is outlined here, complete with a glaring typo in the example code (it should be a link, not an anchor tag).

However I am concerned that adding links to both accounts might be a bad idea.

Can anyone confirm this is OK?

Comment: "website is outlined here" - is there supposed to be a link there somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should merge the Google+ and Google Local pages - this is the norm now and what Google has even started doing automatically (albeit, it's a bit of a mess in true Google fashion).

[This is a business](https://plus.google.com/+Clubnetsem) that has a merged page/local profile for example. Thus only requiring one link to website with verification. The automatic process that Google has started deploying has a habit of leaving duplicate/redundant profiles in their G+ system though so requires you to delete any dupes post-merge.

Comment: Leave a comment to explain why if you're going to downvote.